# SQL problem: same column in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

hy!
I have 2 tables and in each I have a column date, I need to make a single table with the information from all 2 tables with a column date which i want to get from the 3 tables,but in the same column
i tried the following code, but didn`t work

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetContactInformation(@id int)
RETURNS @retActivityInformation TABLE 
(
ClientID int NOT NULL,
ActivityDate datetime NULL,
Tipe nvarchar(50) NULL,
Number nvarchar(50) NULL,
Value int NULL,
Statu nvarchar(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (clientID ASC)

) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ClientID int,
        @ActivityDate datetime, 
        @Tip nvarchar(50), 
        @Number nvarchar(50),
        @Value int,
        @Statu nvarchar(50);
       SELECT 
        @ClientID = ClientID, 
        @ActivityDate = ActivityDate, 
        @Number = Number,
        @Value = Value,
        @Statu = Statu
    FROM Fa,Pay 
    WHERE ID = @id;
    SET @ActivityDate = 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Fa.DataEmitere FROM Fa AS e 
                WHERE e.ID = @id) 
                THEN 'Fa'           
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Pay.Data FROM Pay AS bec
                WHERE bec.ID = @id) 
                THEN 'Pay'            
        END;

    IF @id IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retActivityInformation
        SELECT @clientID, @ActivityDate,  @Number, @Value,@Statu;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: `sql` is a generic tag, do you mean `sql-server`?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here. The `SET @ActivityDate = 'FA'` piece is clearly wrong. Could you post some sample data and your expected results (preferably more than one example)?

Comment: You have a cartesian join here that none of the answers seems to have picked up on ` FROM Fa,Pay `

Answer (score 0):

Just prefix the field with the database name. I am going to assume the date you actually mean is `ActivityDate`. If you want to SELECT/INSERT using this field you will need to prefix with `Fa` or `Pay` so it would be `Fa.ActivityDate` or `Pay.ActivityDate`.

If this is not the field then we'd need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the column by specifying the table name as below:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetContactInformation(@id int)
RETURNS @retActivityInformation TABLE 
(
ClientID int NOT NULL,
ActivityDate datetime NULL,
Tipe nvarchar(50) NULL,
Number nvarchar(50) NULL,
Value int NULL,
Statu nvarchar(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (clientID ASC)

) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ClientID int,
        @ActivityDate datetime, 
        @Tip nvarchar(50), 
        @Number nvarchar(50),
        @Value int,
        @Statu nvarchar(50);
       SELECT 
        @ClientID = ClientID, 
        @ActivityDate = Fa.ActivityDate, 
        @Number = Number,
        @Value = Value,
        @Statu = Statu
    FROM Fa,Pay 
    WHERE ID = @id;
    SET @ActivityDate = 
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Fa.DataEmitere FROM Fa AS e 
                WHERE e.ID = @id) 
                THEN 'Fa'           
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Pay.Data FROM Pay AS bec
                WHERE bec.ID = @id) 
                THEN 'Pay'            
        END;

    IF @id IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retActivityInformation
        SELECT @clientID, @ActivityDate,  @Number, @Value,@Statu;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

See the middle part here:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetContactInformation(@id int)
RETURNS @retActivityInformation TABLE 
(
ClientID int NOT NULL,
ActivityDate datetime NULL,
Tipe nvarchar(50) NULL,
Number nvarchar(50) NULL,
Value int NULL,
Statu nvarchar(50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (clientID ASC)

) AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ClientID int,
        @ActivityDate datetime, 
        @Tip nvarchar(50), 
        @Number nvarchar(50),
        @Value int,
        @Statu nvarchar(50);
       SELECT 
        @ClientID = ClientID, 
        @ActivityDate = ActivityDate, 
        @Number = Number,
        @Value = Value,
        @Statu = Statu
    FROM Fa,Pay 
    WHERE ID = @id;
    SET @ActivityDate = ISNULL(
        (SELECT top 1 Fa.DataEmitere FROM Fa AS e WHERE e.ID = @id),
        (SELECT top 1 Pay.Data FROM Pay AS bec WHERE bec.ID = @id))

    IF @id IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        INSERT @retActivityInformation
        SELECT @clientID, @ActivityDate,  @Number, @Value,@Statu;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

Essentially, instead of testing to see if the data EXISTS just to get the field name, get the data directly.